# How to use SqlServerConnection class in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I write this block of code in `Startup.cs` file to define my database connection:

```
services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(
    db => new SqlServerConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<IETrackerContext>();
```

But I get an error saying that the input of `SqlServerConnection` class cannot be a string.

So how can I introduce my connection string to that class?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using an EF Core class when you want to create a low-level ADO.NET `IDbConnection` ? Doesn't really make much sense to me .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would register a `DbContext` descendant for EF Core in your `startup.cs` - something like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Here, the `connectionString` is just a string - as you seem to have.

See [this MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for a starting point how to configure and then use EF Core in your app

If you really want to configure just the `IDbConnection` for your .NET Core dependency injection, use something like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(db => 
    new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString")));
```

Use the `SqlConnection` class from ADO.NET - not `SqlServerConnection` from EF Core ....